# Intellisense not working in MS Test files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, mstest

In Visual Studio 2013 I have a unit test project (MS Test) which, all of a sudden, no longer seems to support intellisense. I type `Assert.` and no suggestions appear, but if I type something invalid it does underline it as an error.

Intellisense is working on my main project without issue. My settings are as follows:

[image]

I should add that making "Hide advanced members" ticked makes no difference. Unticking, saving then reticking also makes no difference.

Has anybody experienced this before, maybe is VS2012?

Comment: I'm having the same issue...what can help is to Clean the solution and then rebuild

Answer (score 4):

I had a exactly same issue.
Intellisense was working only on my main project not on unit test project.

In my case, it came back after I closed VS 2013 and restarted it.

Clean and Rebuild does not change anything.
Changing Options of Text Editor made no difference.

I made Unit Test project long time after I build my main project.
Maybe global options somehow twisted while I was making Test Project.

Anyway simply restarting VS2013 solved my problem.

Hope it helps.